# Pointer to a function in C#

Tags: c#, function-pointers

I would like to write a function like this:

```
class Form 
{
    private void Foo()
    {
        int bar = 42;
        function myF = func1;

        if(today.weather == sunny)
            myF = func2;

        myF(bar);
    }

    private void func1(int bar) 
    {
        // do something
    }

    private void func2(int bar)
    {
        // do something
    }
}
```

i need a pointer to a function (like C), it's possible to create one?

Comment: That's called a `Delegate` in C#.

Comment: Take a look at [Action<T>](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/018hxwa8.aspx).

Comment: This will help beginners http://www.dotnetperls.com/delegate

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You're looking for a [`Delegate`](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/900fyy8e.aspx)

```
class Form 
{
    private void Foo()
    {
        int bar = 42;
        Action<int> myF = func1; //<-- Action<T> is a delegate 

        if(today.weather == sunny)
            myF = func2;

        myF(bar);
    }

    private void func1(int bar) 
    {
        // do something
    }

    private void func2(int bar)
    {
        // do something
    }
}
```

Answer (score 2):

Look into [Delegates (C# Programming Guide)](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ms173171%28v=vs.90%29.aspx)

```
class Form 
{
    delegate void MyFunction (int bar); 
    private void Foo() {
        int bar = 42;
        MyFunction myF = func1;
        if(today.weather == sunny)
            myF = func2;
        myF(bar);
    }
    private void func1(int bar) { 
        // do something 
    }
    private void func2(int bar) {
        // do something 
    }
}
```

Answer (score 2):

You can use a Delegate, but I would prefer a `Func` or `Action` (depending on if there is a return type).

```
class Form 
{
    private void Foo()
    {
        int bar = 42;
        Action<int> myAction = func1;

        if(today.weather == sunny)
            myAction = func2;

        myAction(bar);
    }

    private void func1(int bar) 
    {
        // do something
    }

    private void func2(int bar)
    {
        // do something
    }
}
```

Answer (score 0):

Take a look at: http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ms173171(v=vs.90).aspx

You can either create your own `delegate`:

```
delegate void MyDel(int x);
```

or use a pre-defined one:

```
Action<Int>
```

In either case, these can be used to create what you need.